# PHP, Format Number to have always have 2 decimal places

Tags: php, number-formatting

In PHP I have decimal numbers that may or may not have trailing zeros.

For example

```
 1
 1.1
43.87
```

How do I make sure that all these numbers have exactly two decimal places like this:

```
 1.00
 1.10
43.87
```

Comment: Check out [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Comment: http://php.net/number-format

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format(1.1, 2);
```

Comment: You're not an idiot my friend, don't get embarrassed by learn something :)

Answer (score -1):

**For laravel:**

```
{!! number_format((float)($item->amount), 2) !!}
```

**For Raw PHP:**

```
number_format((float)($yourVariable), 2)
```

Comment: I did for additional help.