# How to display integers with decimals, in .csv file generated with Spreadsheet (), php?

Tags: php, spreadsheet

Currently I generate the .csv with this function, basically I just pass it an array for the rows to create in the .csv file

```
public function make_csv_file($data)
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

        //create csv file
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1');

        $writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);

        $writer->setDelimiter(',');
        $writer->setEnclosure('');
        $writer->setLineEnding("\r\n");
        $writer->setSheetIndex(0);

        header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.csv"');

        return $writer;
    }
```

As you will see the quantity 113033, I need to show it as 113033.00 and 555.13 if it is ok like this. The detail is that in the arrangement that happened to it if it goes as 113033.00 but the library passes it to 113033

[image]

I tried:

```
  $sheet->getStyle('M1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00);
```

But it's not working

Comment: You will most likely need to format the data in the column using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898638/php-format-number-to-have-always-have-2-decimal-places to give it 2 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files don't have formatting, that is up to the program that read them to interpret things as they wish. If you want to format a number in a certain way, you have to store the value as a string which you probably don't want to do. The alternative is to use a file format like Excel which does support formatting.